# Is this question wrong? Sequence of polynomial approximates $\sin$

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples

> Prove that there cannot be a sequence of polynomial $p_n$ converging uniformly to $\cos$ or $\sin$ on $\Bbb R$.

Doesn't the Taylor series completely contradict this question?

Comment: Do Taylor series converge uniformly on $\mathbb R$?

Comment: @bof, sorry I wrote it down, but didn't realize it…I am a little under weather, that's probably why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Taylor series of a bounded function that converges on all of $\mathbb{R}$ never converges uniformly to that function because the difference between every partial sum of the series and some point in its limit is as large as you want to make it. Polynomials increase in absolute value without bound as we stray far enough from 0.

Comment: I am an idiot. For some reason I was thinking that $x \in (-1,1)$ only.

Comment: @jip That doesn't make you an idiot, it means you were correct! You were just considering the wrong problem.